# Android RSS Xml Error

Tags: java, android, xml, dom, rss

Im trying to parse a Xml file from a URL, the xml is actually a RSS feed. However when I call

```
Document dom = builder.parse(podcastUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

or

```
Document dom = builder.parse(new InputSource(podcastUrl.openStream()));
```

I get this exception thrown :

```
unterminated entity ref (position:ENTITY_REF &T@7:14 in java.io.InputStreamReader@47b601c0)
```

podcast is of Type URL.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `http://podcast.mediamosaicfl.org/podcast.xml`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a link

http://devtuts.mobi/Android:RSS_Parser

Explains a different way of doing it. Works Great!!

Answer (score 4):

I was also having the similar problem. And after searching the reason, I found that if xml is not well formatted (means it contains `&` or other chars without being formatted) this error is thrown. I had to fix such issues to make it work.

In my case `&`is to be converted to `&amp;`, so simple but consumed my some time to know it.

Answer (score 2):

The exception message sounds like the feed is actually not well-formed XML. This is most likely caused by an unescaped ampersand (`&`) in the query string of a link. The link might have looked like this:

```
http://example.com/?A=1&T=2
```

An XML parser would try to interpret the part starting with `&T` as a character entity and complain that it is not terminated by a semicolon. In a XML document the `&` sign has to be escaped like this:

```
http://example.com/?A=1&amp;T=2
```

The link you posted as a comment parses OK, so it might have been just a temporary problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RSS FEED LIBRARY to parse the rss feed urls. Just look at my answer here I think this is helpful to you [Android Xml Parsing Null Pointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397058/android-xml-parsing-null-pointer-exception/8397284#8397284)